# How can I shorten this basic python function further? (Details in description)

Tags: python

I'm currently taking a very basic programming class for college, and for this final project, we need to make a program that calculates windchill. Long story short, this is a v e r y basic class, and no, I can't skip it. The only bare strips of sanity left I have left in that class are found in making the easy tasks harder or unnecessarily adding dumb features. For those concerned about academic honesty, I've already completed the project, and will not submit any code given to me. I'm looking for ideas and creative minds to maybe crack this down another line or two of code, and thought I'd humbly offer it unto the great programmers of stack overflow. Here is a code segment of two functions in my code.

```
def to_f(c):
    return c*9/5+32
def wind_chill(temp,wind):
    return 35.74 + 0.6215*temp - 35.75*wind**0.16 + 0.4275*temp*wind**0.16
```

I've been thinking, and there must be some way to make these into one function that has less than 4 lines, including the declaration. I'm trying to have the function only return certain variables, as the project requires there be a function that calculates wind chill and one that calculates the temp conversion (not necessarily separate).

Also: I can change what the value of the variables are when passed.
Good luck!

Edit:
Sorry for the lack of explanation, I'm not a good asker of questions. I did find a solution though.

```
def master(c,temp,wind):
    return str(35.74+0.6215*temp-35.75*wind**0.16+0.4275*temp*wind**0.16)+" "+str(c*9/5+32)
```

Using this, I pass all of the variables and use split(" ") when I call the function to take the portion of the return value that I actually want.

Edit again:
Thanks for the advice: using this, I managed to get the code down to less lines of codes than there are requirements for the project. I don't see any way to shorten this further. Also I apologize to the gods of programming that are commenting saying that the code is gross, but then again, this is 100% supposed to be gross and unreadable. I'm also a bit of an amateur. But anyways, here's the final code:

```
master=lambda c,temp,wind : str(35.74+0.6215*temp-35.75*wind**0.16+0.4275*temp*wind**0.16)+" "+str(c*9/5+32)
inp=input("What is the temperature? (Include F/C at end, example: 30F, 20C) ").replace(" ","")
if inp[len(inp)-1:].lower()=="c": inp=str(master(float(inp[0:len(inp)-1]),1,1).split(" ")[1])+inp[len(inp)-1:]
for i in range(5,65,5): print(f"At {round(float(inp[:len(inp)-1]),1)}F and a wind speed of {i} mph, the windchill is {round(float(master(0,float(inp[:len(inp)-1]),i).split(' ')[0]),2)}F.")
```

Comment: understanding that your task here is to have fun and you are knowingly making easy tasks harder, it seems like a bad idea to combine these two functions into one. They do different things - one converts temperature between different units, and one calculates windchill. Those are just completely different things... You could do something weird where you have three parameters, all optional, and you check if the 'c' param exists and then do the conversion if it does, otherwise you assume that 'temp' and 'wind' exist and do the wind-chill calc. Or i completely misunderstand what you are asking

Comment: Please provide more of your code, because as is your question is mostly incomprehensible

Comment: You might like : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can make them fewer lines (see lambda functions) but conceptually they do two things. Do you want one method that takes 3 parameters?

Comment: Note that short code isn't necessarily good code!  Might help to have a slightly longer function that explains what's going on.  E.g., what units are these supposed to be in, I'm assuming not sensible ones like °C and m/s

Comment: _Using this, I pass all of the variables and use split(" ") when I call the function to take the portion of the return value that I actually want._ Oh, boy.... Ignoring that it is not good idea to combine the two, as already explained, why not just return a 2 element tuple instead of string?

Comment: It seems to me like you are overvaluing your python (and math) skills. Lookup "multiple return values in python". Lookup "f-strings". Lookup "Distributive property" (In your case it can be applied to `wind**0.16`)

Comment: How about this monstrosity `wind_chill = lambda temp, speed, is_metric=True : 13.12 + 0.6215 * temp - 11.37 * speed ** 0.16 + 0.4275 * temp * speed ** 0.16 if is_metric else 35.74 + 0.6215 * temp - 35.75 * speed ** 0.16 + 0.3965 * temp * speed ** 0.16`

Comment: shouldnt Pyhton be about code clarity and self explicative with function annotation and type hints and reusability instead of shortening up ??

Answer (score 0):

> I've been thinking, and there must be some way to make these into one function that has less than 4 lines, including the declaration.

You have two completely different computations to perform, so to use one function for both tasks, that function needs to be able to determine from its arguments which operation is wanted.  Since the two operations have different numbers of inputs, you might do that by giving one argument a recognizable default value.  For example:

```
def do_everything(temp, wind=None):
    if wind is None:
        print("F to C")
    else:
        print("wind chill")
```

You can reduce the actual computation to just one line for both cases via inline `if` / `else`:

```
    return "F to C" if wind is None else "wind chill"
```

Between these approaches, you can achieve the dubious distinction of a two-line function that does both jobs, albeit with one of those lines very long.

How awful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to shorten it into 2 lines of code where you combine it into one function `calculate_wind_chill()`.

Here is the code:

```
def calculate_wind_chill(temp_celsius, wind_speed):
    return 35.74 + 0.6215 * temp_celsius - 35.75 * wind_speed ** 0.16 + 0.4275 * temp_celsius * wind_speed ** 0.16
```